# Javascript change html or body css

Tags: javascript

I use in my webpage the css description

```
    body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    background: url(images/diffdummy.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

How I can remove the background image with java script on runtime? I tried

```
document.getElementById("html").style.background="";
document.getElementsByTagName("html").style.background="";
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.background="";
```

But nothing is working. Anybody here who can give me a hint?

Comment: `document.body.style.background = 'none'`

Comment: Class is set on the body, but you are selecting the html element?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why `html` when you are using `body` as your CSS selector?

just use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = "none";
```

or

```
document.body.style.background = "none";
```

Code in action!

```js
// removing background-color from body
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = "none";
```

```css
body {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Many thanks,  this document.body.style.background = "none"; works. I know the body was confusing but I tried both so sorry for this confusion.

Comment: @Ingo Its fine bro, we all make beginner mistakes when we started as well.

Answer (score 0):

just to remove the background image should do like:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "none";
```

to avoid i.e. removing background-color or other css props that might be applied to just `background`